# Transaction Reverted when calling a function to send Tether USDT from Contract to wallet address

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transfer, usdt

I have a function that uses the ERC20 transfer function to send an ERC20 token from a smart contract to another wallet address.

```
function withdrawTokens(address _tokenContract, uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
    IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(_tokenContract);
    tokenContract.transfer(_wallet, _amount);
    emit FundsWithdrawn(_wallet, _amount);
}
```

For some reason this is not working for sending Tether USDT (`0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7`) out of the contract, but it does work for sending USDC. Is Tether non ERC-20 compliant? How do I implement this function to work for USDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No USDT is a black sheep amongst ERC20 tokens. Not only does it have only 6 decimals, but it also has special transfer and approve functions.

Firstly transfer function does not return any boolean if successful or not. That is why you should always use `safeTransfer` instead of checking the return status.

```
// Forward ERC20 methods to upgraded contract if this one is deprecated
function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public whenNotPaused {
    require(!isBlackListed[msg.sender]);
    if (deprecated) {
        return UpgradedStandardToken(upgradedAddress).transferByLegacy(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    } else {
        return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }
}
```

Secondly, when setting approval, you should always first set it to 0 and then to desired amount otherwise it fails.

Comment: Thanks, shocking that they haven't upgraded